# In an HTTP GET request to a Node.js webserver, how does the client know which assets to request?

Tags: node.js, express, http

I have a node/express webserver and when I direct my browser to a URL like '/' I'll see the requests come in by doing

```
console.log(req.url);
```

The first URL is always just the endpoint itself ex. `/`. After that though the client immediately starts sending other new requests for `myJavaScript.js`, `myStyle.css`, `myHTML.html`, etc. The key is, these are all separate requests. The server didn't respond with a big directory of assets, *the client made an individual request for each asset*.

How does the client know which assets to request? Presumably the client can't know that `myStyle.css` exists unless my server tells him so. My server knows which assets should be sent for any given URL because I wrote it in the server code, specifically, by using `express.static()`. So how does the client know which URLs to request?

My suspicion is that when the endpoint is requested (`/`), the response includes a list of URLs for assets that should be requested by the client in the immediate future. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client knows, because the client reads the HTML, and in your HTML you point to those urls.

Your HTML probably has a `<link rel="stylesheet" />` tag, so it reads that and grabs what it needs. It's really the core feature of the web, everything is a link and clients use links to figure out what to do next.

Comment: Ah ok so the response to `/` is index.html and then the rest of the assets are derived from that?

Comment: Yes, usually so.